# Android Studio not committing to GitHub

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am trying to use git in Android Studio. If I choose commit changes, it says that it has successfully committed the changed files but those changes do not appear on the GitHub. Instead, if I delete the repository from GitHub and choose Share Project on GitHub, it successfully creates a new repository and uploads the files into it. This means that the connection is fine. Also, I have checked the gitignore file, the java files are not in that list. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you push the changes, or just commit?

Comment: Thanks man! My mistake, bad question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Commit and Push Android App/Project to Pre-existing Empty Bitbucket Repository with Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376789/how-to-commit-and-push-android-app-project-to-pre-existing-empty-bitbucket-repos)

Comment: Not duplicate, I got confused between push and commit. First time with git. Sorry.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to select "commit and push".

If you want to upload (push) the changes that you made, go to:

```
VCS -> Git -> PUSH
```

Only after "pushing", your changes will be uploaded to GitHub.

If you select "commit", your changes would remain local.

Comment: That was such a pathetic question. Thanks anyways! Will improve on this.

Comment: No problem... It happens sometimes :)

Comment: I'm just waiting for the down vote notifications. :D

Answer (score 16):

For my case it's a different - I uncheck **Perform code analysis** in commit changes dialog and it worked. Hope it will help some one.

Comment: Worked for me. Why could this happen?