# Java files doesn't appear in BITBUCKET repository after commit in Android studio

Tags: java, android, git, bitbucket

Hi this is my first time using Git in my Android application. After finished the importation of the project towards my BitBucket repository, I found only this instead of all my `.java` files. [image: My repository in bitbucket]
I supposed it should contain all the files below:

[image: Android Studio]

I tried to commit the files one by one, but I got this error instead

> fatal: bad revision 'f504b88046e682c25d49aa3b3c70178776799990:.'

I don't understand why this is happening. I follow the importation steps here [How to import a Project into bitbucket repository from Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099244/how-to-import-a-project-into-bitbucket-repository-from-android-studio) . Can someone lend me a hand please?

Comment: `git push -f --set-upstream origin master`. Forces a new push (overriding all existing files btw, so be careful when using the `-f` or `-force` flag). It'll give you a new copy on BitBucket

Comment: i did this in my terminal, and got this as an output `Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date` However, nothing changes when I refresh the page..still the same problem @Zoe

Comment: Try removing `--set-upstream` and `master`. Keep `origin` and the `-f` flag