# Android Studio: how to move a project from bitbucket repository A to bitbucket repository B

Tags: git

I want to reuse a project, which was connected to `Repository` A.
I've been following the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710073/1907742 and I could successfully connect my project to repository A.

I copied the project. Now, how can I move it to `Repository` B?

Comment: Please describe your scenario. What you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Actually, if I make a commit and push the new project (B), it goes on the repo A. I want to keep the project A in the repo A, and the new copied project B in the repository B, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
This is exactly what I wanted to realize, reset the actual git.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31991358/1907742

> In order to drop the current git repository and create a new one you need to:
>   Go to the project's directory: cd PROJECT_DIRECTORY
>   Remove all the git specific files: rm -rf $(find . -name ".git*")
>   Initialize a new git repository: git init

Thank you and sorry if I didn't make my self clear enough.
Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

The project can have several repositories connected, called `origin` (the most usual name) or `backup` or whatever you like. You may create a link to another remove repository B:

```
git remote add repo_b https://bitbucket.com/user/repo_b.git
```

and then

```
git push repo_b
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone repository A on your local first then, add a remote to the repository B as follow:

```
$> git clone <your-bitbucket-repo-A-url>
$> git remote add bitbucket_origin_b <your-bitbucket-repo-B-url>
```

you can now see this added remote by running:

```
$> git remote -v
```

Now, push your local version of the repository A to the bitbucket repository B:

```
$> git push bitbucket_origin_b <your-branch-name> # <your-branch-name> is where you're checked-out to locally 
it can be seen by:
$> git branch
```

Adding remote: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/