# Copy android studio project to new computer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android Studio project that was built on a MacBook Pro 2012 with Android Studio version April 18. The app works great. I am trying to copy the project to a new MacBook Pro 2018 with the same Sndroid Studio version (April 18) with no success.

I have dozens of errors. Does anyone know a good guide or advise how to do it well?

Comment: refer this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099244/how-to-import-a-project-into-bitbucket-repository-from-android-studio).Use bit bucket to share your project and you can get it in any computer'

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it was'nt resolved my problem. still having the same errors. I uploaded the project to bitbucket, download in the new computer and get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to import your project to a zip file. Simply go to:

- File->Import project-> Select the location you want to import.

In your other computer, uncompress the zip file, open a existing project and choose the folder of your uncompressed zip.